# aggregation of an ordered dataframe based on conditional accumulated previous values in a group (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, aggregate, accumulate

I've got an ordered dataframe which I'm trying to aggregate by some grouping columns and based on accumulated previous values of other columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID2','ID2','ID2','ID2']
            , 'Group':['Group1','Group2','Group2','Group2','Group1','Group2','Group2','Group2','Group1']
            , 'Value1':[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
            , 'Value2':[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,2]})


df
        ID  Group   Value1  Value2
    0   ID1 Group1    0       1
    1   ID1 Group2    1       2
    2   ID1 Group2    1       3
    3   ID1 Group2    1       4
    4   ID1 Group1    1       5
    5   ID2 Group2    1       4
    6   ID2 Group2    0       3
    7   ID2 Group2    0       2
    8   ID2 Group1    0       2
```

I'd like to aggregate three different ways using Value1 and Value 2, Grouped by ID and Group.
df is already ordered (based on date, ID and Group)

> Output1: count the number of 1s in previous rows of Value1, by ID and Group (excluding the row itself)
>
> Output2: sum the value of previous rows of Value2, by ID and Group (including the row itself)
>
> Output3: sum Value2 of previous rows, by ID and Group, if Value1 of those previous rows is 1 (excluding the row itself)

here's my desired output:

```
    ID  Group   Value1  Value2  Output1 Output2 Output3
0   ID1 Group1    0       1        0      1       NaN
1   ID1 Group2    1       2        0      2       NaN
2   ID1 Group2    1       3        1      5        2
3   ID1 Group2    1       4        2      9        5
4   ID1 Group1    1       5        0      6       NaN 
5   ID2 Group2    1       4        0      4       NaN
6   ID2 Group2    0       3        1      7        4
7   ID2 Group2    0       2        1      9        4
8   ID2 Group1    0       2        0      2       NaN
```

To make sure it's clear what I'm trying to do, let's look at the output index 3 (the fourtth row)

```
3   ID1 Group2    1       4        2      9        5
```

> Output1 = 2 because there are two rows above it in ID1/Group2 that has
> Value1 = 1.
>
> Output2 = 9 because the sum of Value2 of all rows above it in
> ID1/Group2, including the row itself is (2+3+4 = 9).
>
> Output3 = 5, because there are two previous rows in ID1/Group2 that have Value1 = 1, so some of their Value2 (2 + 3 = 5)

I'd like to add I'm working on a large dataset, so I'm looking for an efficient/high performance solution.

Comment: I realized I misread the condition of shift. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71612579/16343464)

Comment: There was a typo in one of the group names (Gr**uo**p2) can you double-check the provided output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

- For Output 1 and 2: We can use `groupby + cumsum`
- For Output 3: Its a little tricky calculation as you have to first the mask the values in column `Value2` where the corresponding value in column Value1 is 0, after that you need to group the masked column and use `cumsum` to calculate cumulative sum now in order to exclude the current row you have can subtract the masked column from the cummulative sum

```
g = df.groupby(['ID', 'Group'])
df['Output1'] = g['Value1'].cumsum() - df['Value1']
df['Output2'] = g['Value2'].cumsum()

s = df['Value2'].mul(df['Value1'])
df['Output3'] = s.groupby([df['ID'], df['Group']]).cumsum() - s
```

Update as per the new requirements in the comments:

```
def transform(g):
    g['Output1'] = g['Value1'].cumsum() - g['Value1']
    g['Output2'] = g['Value2'].cumsum()

    cond = g['Value1'].eq(1)
    g['Output3'] = g['Value2'].mask(~cond).cumsum().shift().ffill()
    return g


df.groupby(['ID', 'Group']).apply(transform)
```

Result

```
print(df)

    ID   Group  Value1  Value2  Output1  Output2  Output3
0  ID1  Group1       0       1        0        1      NaN
1  ID1  Group2       1       2        0        2      NaN
2  ID1  Group2       1       3        1        5      2.0
3  ID1  Group2       1       4        2        9      5.0
4  ID1  Group1       1       5        0        6      NaN
5  ID2  Group2       1       4        0        4      NaN
6  ID2  Group2       0       3        1        7      4.0
7  ID2  Group2       0       2        1        9      4.0
8  ID2  Group1       0       2        0        2      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. This is amazingly close to what I need. Output1 and Output2 are great. My problem is that there is a difference between NaN in my desired Output3 and your Output3 with zeros. I want those rows with NaN to appear as NaN, because they're not the same as zero in my application. Also, I happen to give one condition, for which you could use .mul function. Could you please provide an answer with any boolean condition, rather than a calculated condition? (for example, condition that (Value1 > 0 & Value1 < 5) rather than my example that was Value1 == 1)

Comment: ah, I guess for any condition I could use s = ((df['Value1'] > 0) & (df['Value1'] <5)).mul(df['Value2'])
I just need to bring the NaN in and I'm sorted! :)

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira Let me get back to you in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a masked column for the third output and computer a grouped, shifted cumsum:

```
import numpy as np

# dictionary of shift values
d_shift = {'Value1': 1, 'Value3': 1}
# dictionary of fill values
d_fill  = {'Value1': 0}

df[['Output1', 'Output2', 'Output3']] = (df
 .assign(Value3=df['Value2'].where(df['Value1'].eq(1)))
 .groupby(['ID', 'Group'])
 .transform(lambda x: x.shift(d_shift.get(x.name, 0),
                              fill_value=d_fill.get(x.name, np.nan)).cumsum())
)
```

Or, as linear form:

```
g = (df.assign(Value3=df['Value2']
       .mask(df['Value1'].ne(1))).groupby(['ID', 'Group'])
     )
df['Output1'] = g['Value1'].apply(lambda s: s.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
df['Output2'] = g['Value2'].cumsum()
df['Output3'] = g['Value3'].apply(lambda s: s.shift().cumsum())
```

output:

```
    ID   Group  Value1  Value2  Output1  Output2  Output3
0  ID1  Group1       0       1        0        1      NaN
1  ID1  Group2       1       2        0        2      NaN
2  ID1  Group2       1       3        1        5      2.0
3  ID1  Group2       1       4        2        9      5.0
4  ID1  Group1       1       5        0        6      NaN
5  ID2  Group2       1       4        0        4      NaN
6  ID2  Group2       0       3        1        7      4.0
7  ID2  Group2       0       2        1        9      NaN
8  ID2  Group1       0       2        0        2      NaN
```